# EF Core many-to-many configuration for a single table to a new table

Tags: entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have a Product table with columns Id etc. For each product I might have one or many similar products according to my business model. So I've to create a "SimilarProductMapping" table. SimilarProductMapping content will be like;

| Id | ProductId | SimilarProductId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |
| 2 | 10 | 30 |
| 3 | 20 | 10 |
| 4 | 20 | 30 |
| 5 | 30 | 10 |
| 6 | 30 | 20 |

I want to use the navigation like product.SimilarProducts.
How can I model and configure such a requirement in EF Core?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SimilarProductMapping>().HasKey(spm=> new {spm.ProductId, spm.SimilarProductId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasOne<SimilarProduct>(p => p.Product)
    .WithMany(sp => sp.SimilarProduct)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);


modelBuilder.Entity<SimilarProduct>()
    .HasOne<Product>(sp => sp.SimilarProduct)
    .WithMany(p => p.Product)
    .HasForeignKey(sp => sp.SimilarProductId);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, there is no "SimilarProduct" entity, it's just Product and it's self mappings on SimilarproductMapping table.